# Pandas Dataframe Set value in cell if condition (Element is in list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a column called "column_B" with only nan-values. It contains also "column_A", which is a list of strings for every cell in the dataframe.

```
index   column_A    column_B  
1       ['A','B']    np.nan
2       ['B']        np.nan
3       ['C']        np.nan
```

Now I want that column_B is set to 0 if any element in  a list of column_A contains 'B'.

Desired result:

```
   index   column_A    column_B  
    1       ['A','B']    0
    2       ['B']        0
    3       ['C']        np.nan
```

I tried

```
df['column_B'][any([x == 'B' for x in df['column_A']])] = 0
```

that doesn't work.
Any ideas? :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm if the rows are actual lists or string repr of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for test value in list by `in` and set value in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['column_B'] = df['column_B'].mask(df['column_A'].map(lambda x: 'B' in x), 0)
#df['column_B'] = df['column_B'].mask(df['column_A'].apply(lambda x: 'B' in x), 0)
```

Or by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['column_A'].map(lambda x: 'B' in x), 'column_B'] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Comprehension and `mask`

```
df['column_B'] = df.column_B.mask(['B' in x for x in df.column_A], 0)

df

  column_A  column_B
0   [A, B]       0.0
1      [B]       0.0
2      [C]       NaN
```

---

#### Without `mask`

```
df['column_B'] = [0 if 'B' in x else np.nan for x in df.column_A]

df

  column_A  column_B
0   [A, B]       0.0
1      [B]       0.0
2      [C]       NaN
```

---

#### Explode

```
df['column_B'] = df.column_B.mask(df.column_A.explode().eq('B').any(level=0), 0)

df

  column_A  column_B
0   [A, B]       0.0
1      [B]       0.0
2      [C]       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
df['column_B'] = np.where(df['column_A'].astype(str).str.contains(r'\bB\b'), 0, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    index   column_A    column_B
0   1      ['A','B']      0.0
1   2       ['B']         0.0
2   3       ['C']         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

using `explode()`:

```
df2 = df.explode('column_A')
df.loc[df2['column_A'].isin(['B']).groupby(level=0).any(),'column_B'] = 0
```